# SharePoint 2010 Workflow Timed Out when Started Automatically

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, dns, list-workflow

I am currently working on a SharePoint 2013 Farm with list workflows (SharePoint Designer Workflow with SharePoint 2010 workflow template) on some of its lists and document libraries.

After reconfiguration of the DNS several days ago, the workflow for each list/library whose set to run automatically whenever list item / document is created/updated, started to behave unexpectedly. Each time a document / list item is added, the workflow will not start and it will throw timed out exception 
 on the ULS (and Something when a wrong error on the web page).

The workflow will start and work normally if it is started manually, but it still took a long time compared to before the DNS reconfiguration.

Any idea about whats going wrong here?

**Update:** The change to the DNS configuration is the IP Address.

**Update:** Finally I was able to get into the server. Here is the error log I've got when the workflow failed to start (based on the correlation ID on the error message):

> A runtime exception was detected. Details follow.  Message: Thread was being aborted.  Technical Details: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
>    at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, UInt32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
>    at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, Int64 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
>    at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
>    at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)
>
>    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)
>
>    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpWorkflowNotificationPublisher.OnPublishNotification(String address, WorkflowNotification notification, ICredentials credentials, String userCulture, Guid traceActivityId, TimeSpan requestTimeout)
>
>    at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManagementClient.PublishNotification(WorkflowNotification notification, IDictionary`2 activationMetadata, Int64 expectedScopeRevision)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowProxy.PublishEvent(String eventSource, String eventType, IDictionary`2 payload, SPUserToken userToken)

Another log record:

> Leaving Monitored Scope (Event Receiver (Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.ContentSubscriptionEventReceiver)). Execution Time=112645.295630776

And

> Loading and running the event receiver class Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.ContentSubscriptionEventReceiver from assembly Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c failed. Thread was being aborted.

The remaining error messages are generic messages, such as Request Timed Out.

Comment: Usually when you run workflow manually, it starts immediately without waiting for Workflow timer job to pick it up. Automatic execution on item create/update event will work within timer job. So I would say you have some issues with Timer Service and/or Topology service.
What change in DNS has been done?
What is the status of Workflow timer job? Does it run without errors? 
You may also enable verbose logging and look for errors related to Workflow timer job

Comment: Hi arax. Thanks, the change we've done to the DNS server is the IP address. Nothing else. I'll let you know the status of the workflow timer job one i have went back to office.

Comment: Hi arax, the workflow did run with error (noted in the workflow history), but since it was logged into the workflow history, there were no details about the error. But please check my updated question, where I've provided more detailed logs from ULS.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please share the detailed error in the ULS log?

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. If there are initiation parameters in your workflow, you should ensure there are default values for all of initiation parameters in the workflow.
2. Re-publish the workflow to check if the work will start automatically.
3. Register the workflow service by the PowerShell code below.
   Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "https://sharepoint.domain.local/" -WorkflowHostUri "http://workflowserver.domain.local:12291/" -AllowOAuthHttp -Force

More references:

Troubleshoot workflow errors (SharePoint Server 2010)
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298927(v=office.14).aspx

SharePoint Workflow Debugging & Troubleshooting.
http://www.czarzbon.com/2011/10/22/sharepoint-workflow-debugging-troubleshooting/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, amy. 1. There is no initiation parameters. 2. I've tried that but no luck. 3. The workflows I've used are 2010 workflow. Please check my updated question including detailed logs from ULS.